# Cakephp model named "Club" not working at all! Reserved keyword?

Tags: cakephp, model

In Cakephp2.0 I have a model named "Club" and I'm accessing it from "ClubsController". If I try do a $this->Club->find inside my controller it says "Error: Database table clubs for model Club was not found."The stack trace has

`.....ClubsController.php(7): Model->find('first', Array)`

The real database table is called "ClubTable" which I have specified in the class with `$useTable = 'ClubTable'`. This leads me to believe it is automatically making a model called "Club" which is different from my model. Folder structure as such:

```
/app/Model/Club.php
/app/Plugin/Admin/Controller/ClubsController.php
```

Now here's the kicker, if I change my Model to Club123.php with a model name of "Club123". Then in the controller I just do `$this->loadModel('Club123');` it works perfectly and loads my model and connects to my database and to the table "ClubTable".

Is "Club" somehow a reserved keyword?

To further confuse the issue, it works fine when I am not using a plugin (creating a ClubsController in the /app/Controllers folder). To sum up the problem:

*The model **Club** cannot be found when called from inside my plugin, but the model **Club123** can be. The model **Club** can be found when not inside the plugin.*

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm pulling my hair out. Oh, I also deleted all the files in the /app/tmp/cache/models/ folder.

Comment: file names should be lover case. why arent u using the Cake Bake feature ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This question has been dead for months. CakePHP's ability to handle various environments using "plugins" proved far too unweildy. CodeIgniter allowed me to easily create nested directories and access common models. So I guess my solution to this problem was: switch to CodeIgniter!

Answer (score 0):

Check your naming conventions carefully.

In the filesystem, all names should be LOWERCASE, with underscores used to separate words.

In PHP, they should be CamelCase.

I'd suggest re-reading [this part of the book](http://book.cakephp.org/view/901/CakePHP-Conventions) to make sure you know everything correctly.

I find that setting up and using [Cake's Bake console](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1522/Code-Generation-with-Bake) will clear up these sorts of issues, as everything is generated automatically :)

Comment: While your answer is correct for CakePHP 1.3 (and below), it is incorrect for CakePHP 2.0 (which is used by MikeMurko). There, the names in the file system are camel cased, see https://github.com/cakephp/docs/blob/master/en/appendices/2-0-migration-guide.rst